# is some special batch processing supported by Qt?

Tags: c++, qt5

I want to use some special kind of batch processing. Say when executing in the menu system 'File Open filename', I store this text, and next time I "execute" that "batch" file. The File and Open recognized as menu items, and filename is used, without opening a dialog. Is this utilization supported by Qt? Or, at least finding a menu action?

Comment: Try to clarify the question. It is not obvious what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Dusteh Please read the second (and maybe the third) sentence again and tell what is your difficulty with understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu entries are [`QAction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html)'s. Those could easily be stored, but from your description it seems that you want to also store the filename. That means you want to store *half* a `QAction`; the part which asks for a filename but not the second part which uses that filename. That's not possible with Qt.

Of course, you can implement that yourself; after all it's *your* "File Open" menu entry.

Comment: OK, that is what I supposed. Yes, I want to reproduce  the action the user did. Is there some easy path to find out that "File/Open" is a legal item in the menu system, and which QAction belogns to it?

Comment: @katang: Yes, by remembering that _you_ created the menu! There's a File/Open because you decided to have it.